# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: "no swt-win32-4623" running Visualization Customizer

Tags: java, jar, java-8, executable-jar

I'm trying to install visualization tool using jar from [here](https://community.watsonanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Visualization_Customizer_11_x64-1.zip?cm_mc_uid=29258306289515226236739&cm_mc_sid_50200000=38657501522623673998&cm_mc_sid_52640000=58551231522623674005).

The command I used to install is `java -jar /home/user/Visualization_Customizer_11_x64-1/VisualizationCustomizer.jar`.

But the command returns the below error -

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
            no swt-win32-4623 in java.library.path
            no swt-win32 in java.library.path
            Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32-4623.so
            Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32.so

            at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.vizbundler.VizBundler.main(VizBundler.java:147)
```

When I looked into the list of files in `/home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/` folder, it is empty.

where can I get the missing libraries and fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are attempting to run a Windows-only version of Visualization Customizer on a Linux machine.  The error messages offer important clues:

```
   Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32-4623.so
```

1. The pathname of the directory is clearly a linux directory.
2. The name of the native library is "libswt-win32-..." implies that it is trying to load the SWT native libraries for Windows.

Looking at the documentation, I found this:

> ### Installing and starting the Visualization Customizer
>
> The IBM® Cognos® Visualization Customizer is available as a compressed
>   file.
>
> ### Before you begin
>
> The Visualization Customizer is supported only on Microsoft Windows
>   operating systems.

In short, what you are trying to do (run the tool on Linux) probably won't work.

It is highly unlikely that you will find libraries `libswt-win32-4623.so` and / or `libswt-win32.so` that actually work on a Linux platform.

Your best bet is to use a Windows machine, or run up a Windows virtual on your Linux machine (if it has enough RAM).